# Visual Studio 2017 quick actions light bulb icon vs. new screwdriver icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've been using Visual Studio 2017 Professional Preview for a number of months now, and I just installed the most-recent update yesterday: 15.7.0.  I noticed a new screwdriver icon I've never seen before used for *some* of the quick actions in place of the familiar light bulb icon.  Take the following code for example:

```
internal sealed class ObjectCollection<T>
{
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>> _loaderOperation;

    internal T Items { get; }

    internal ObjectCollection(Func<IEnumerable<T>> loaderOperation) =>
        _loaderOperation = loaderOperation;
}
```

If you place the cursor on the line with the constructor, the quick action icon shows up on the side with the light bulb that I've always seen:

[image]

But then if I put the cursor on the line with the property, the new screwdriver icon shows up:

[image]

If I expand the quick actions, the only difference I see is that the one with the light bulb has a link to a Bing article at the top as well as a "Fix all occurrences in:" thing at the bottom:

[image]

vs the one with the screwdriver:

[image]

I googled this of course, but [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/144425/qiuck-action-icon-no-longer-a-lightbulb.html) is the only reference to the screwdriver that I've found, a MS dev community issue post which (of course) was never sufficiently resolved. I attempted running VS in safe mode as the MS employee suggested, but that didn't change anything.

So what is the significance of the new screwdriver vs. old light bulb for quick actions?

Comment: I noticed this today as I updated to 15.7.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was puzzled by this too, but did find a definition (of sorts) at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions

In short, it appears that the screwdriver indicates that there are options where you *can* change the code, whereas the lightbulb indicates that you *should*.

Comment: That's the answer.  Interesting that the article was posted the same day I asked the question!